# Getting files by lastmodified date

Tags: java, file, directory

What is the fastest way to get files by lastmodified date?
I got a directory with some txt files. User can do a research by date, I list all files in the directory by lastmodified date (in File[]) and i search for the right file with the specific date.
I use a collection sort using lastmodified date to sort my files. When I get files from my local drive it's fast but when i want to access to a drive on the netword (private network) it can take about 10 minutes to get a file. I know i can't be quicker than the network but is there a solution that can be really faster than my solution?

exemple for my code :

```
File[] files = repertoire.listFiles();         

Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<File>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(File o1, File o2) {
        return Long.valueOf(o2.lastModified()).compareTo(o1.lastModified());
    }
});

for (File element : files) {
    // i get the right file;
}
```

Thanks for your help

**Here is the solution :**

```
Path repertoiry = Paths.get(repertoire.getAbsolutePath());
final DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(repertoiry, new DirectoryStream.Filter<Path>() {
     @Override
     public boolean accept(Path entry) throws IOException {
          return Files.getLastModifiedTime(entry, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS).toMillis() >= (dateRechercheeA.getTime() - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) && Files.getLastModifiedTime(entry, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS).toMillis() <= (dateRechercheeB.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
     }
});
for (Path path : stream) {
     if (!path.toFile().getName().endsWith("TAM") && !path.toFile().getName().endsWith("RAM")) {
         listFichiers.add(path.toFile());
     }
}
```

Comment: Get a faster network.

Comment: Yes but it's a corporate network. The files are on a server, when i access this server in the same building it's really fast (like 0,11s per files) but when i access them in an other city request time is about 1,30 minutes..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With java 7 NIO package it's possible to filter a directory to list only files wanted.
(Warning `DirectoryStreams` do not iterate through subdirectories.)

```
Path repertoire = Paths.get("[repertoire]");
try ( DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(repertoire, new DirectoryStream.Filter<Path>() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(Path entry) throws IOException {
            return Files.getLastModifiedTime(entry, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS).toMillis() = [DATE_SEARCHED (long)] 
        }
 })){

     for (Path path : stream) {
          // Path filtered...
     }
 }
```

Normally this solution provide better performance than create a full list of file, sort the list and after that iterate over the list to find the right date.

With your code :

```
//use final keyword to permit access in the filter.
final Date dateRechercheeA = new Date();
final Date dateRechercheeB = new Date();

Path repertoire = Paths.get("[repertoire]");
try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(repertoire, new DirectoryStream.Filter<Path>() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(Path entry) throws IOException {
        long entryDateDays = Files.getLastModifiedTime(entry, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS).to(TimeUnit.DAYS);
        return !entry.getFileName().endsWith("TAM") //does not take TAM file
                && !entry.getFileName().endsWith("RAM") //does not take RAM file
                && ((dateRechercheeB == null && Math.abs(entryDateDays - TimeUnit.DAYS.toDays(dateRechercheeA.getTime())) <= 1)
                || (dateRechercheeB != null && entryDateDays >= (TimeUnit.DAYS.toDays(dateRechercheeA.getTime()) - 1) && entryDateDays <= (TimeUnit.DAYS.toDays(dateRechercheeA.getTime()) + 1)));
    }
})) {
    Iterator<Path> it = stream.iterator();
    //Iterate good file...

}
```

The filter is directly made in the accept methods and not after.

[JAVA SE 7 - Files - newDirectoryStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/nio/file/Files.html)

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But i don't know how to implement this because when a user does a research he chooses between 2 dates so for exemple he chooses betwen 24 avril to 27 avril and he gets 3 files. How can I dot it with your solution?

And i can't put my date at this place `[DATE_SEARCHED (long)]`.
I got a date with this format : dateA.getTime() (dateA is a date with format dd/MM/yy) and dateB.getTime()

To be more comprehensive i've updated my post with my whole code.

Comment: Never mind i figured it out. Now I need to test it to know if it's quicker.

Comment: Well i tested this on the network and it works perfectly. Thank you so much ! I'll update my post to give the solution. Thanks again

Comment: Make the filter of TAM/RAM file directly in the filter not after. And don't forget to add try(...){ } to close correctly the DirectoryStream resource like my modification.

Comment: Thanks but one thing entry.getFileName().endswith("TAM") doest not work you need to use entry.toFile().getName() otherwise it doesn't take the end of the path.

Comment: Yes your are right,you can use also something like that `entry.toString().endswith("TAM")`

Comment: ok, and how can I get the last modified file? I tried to get all files and with a system of max and min i found the last modified file. Is there an other solution?

Comment: You need to loop into all files and maintain a variable on the last modified. At the end of the loop, you obtain the last modified file. From my side, I don't see other solution

Comment: I did this : `fichierAjout = null;
max = listeRetourneeTest.get(0);
for (File f : listeRetourneeTest) {
 if (!f.getName().endsWith("TAM") && !f.getName().equals("ALARMES.TXT") && !f.getName().endsWith("RAM")) {
  if (f.lastModified() > max.lastModified()) {
   fichierAjout = f;
   max = f;
  } else {
   fichierAjout = max;
  }
 }
}
listeRetourneeTest.remove(fichierAjout);
listFichiers.add(fichierAjout);`